# Android: How to make camera capture video only of preview size and not full screen?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, android-camera

I am working on an app that needs to capture square videos just like `Instagram`. I used many libraries for the purpose but none helped to capture the video itself in square size. I can make the preview look like square but not the recorded video. For that I have to use `FFMPEG` library for cropping the video after it has been captured. But this process takes too long for 1 minute videos even with 480p `video` capture quality. Someone please guide me to achieve this task.

Libraries that I have used are:
https://github.com/natario1/CameraView for cameraView and http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/ for using ffmpeg.

Commands that I have tried for ffmpeg cropping operation are:

```
command = new String[]{"-y",
                "-f",
                "concat",
                "-safe",
                "0",
                "-i",
                "" + sdCardPathFile,
                "-c:v",
                "libx264",
                "-vf",
                "crop=" + getVideoResolution(),
                "-preset",
                "ultrafast",
                "-qscale",
                "0",
                "-crf",
                "28",
                "-c:a",
                "copy",
                "-flags",
                "+global_header",
                "" + joinedVideoFile.getAbsolutePath()
        };




String[] joinCommand = new String[]{
                "-y",
                "-f",
                "concat",
                "-safe",
                "0",
                "-i",
                "" + sdCardPathFile,
                "-filter:v",
                "crop=480:480",
                "-preset",
                "superfast",
                "-c:a",
                "copy",
                "" + joinedVideoFile.getAbsolutePath()
        };
```

Comment: Similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285931/how-does-instagram-crop-video-in-android-app).

Comment: I believe you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30601802/192373).

Comment: @AlexCohn Tried to explore Grafika but yet to get it done, tried changing those coordinates for rectangle but it's not making it square at all. Any guidelines or points I'm missing?

Comment: When you crop the texture, you change the video that is recorded, not the live preview. Another quirk that I can expect in your case, is that you arranged texture clipping for portrait orientation while the texture was actually landscape, or vice versa.

Comment: Tried a lot but not able to entertain a photo capture from the activity. I took out the camera object from inside of `RenderThread` and called takePicture method. @AlexCohn I really am a newbie with this `TextureView` and `SurfaceView` things and their working.

Comment: Wait a sec, are you speaking about photo capture or video?

Comment: My concern is photo and video capture both, though the thread focused on video capture. And the part where M stuck is this that I'm not being able to use the object of camera class @AlexCohn

Comment: *I'm not being able to use the object of camera class* - I am afraid this explanation is not enough. Maybe you need 1-on-1 professional help?